# limit displayed selections tom-select

Tags: javascript, tom-select

I am using the javascript lib [Tom-Select](https://tom-select.js.org). I would like to limit the *display* of how many items have been selected. I *do not* want to limit the number of actual choices - only how many are displayed. Standard functionality shows all selections in a growing box. I would like to set a limit of `3`. Then if a user selects *more than 3* the box will no longer grow but simply say `4 items selected` (or 5, 6, etc). Bonus points if I could limit selections by the element width instead of a count (forcing the element to always remain on one line of the form).

Comment: Have you found a solution on this?

Comment: @R.Steigmeier I ended up [writing a plugin to do this](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/pull/449) which I gave back to the project, but it was never implemented (and the project itself is maintained lately)

Comment: I guess I found a solution (see below). Let me know if that would have resolved your issue back in the days. KR

Comment: thanks, but as I said, I have my solution. I'm glad you have yours 

Answer (score 0):

You could trick using the render method and the **items.length** array, but how will you then let your users delete their own choices as you don't display the selected items?

```
render: {
            option: function (data, escape) {
                return '<div class="d-flex"><span>' + escape(data.text) + '</span></div>';
            },
            item: function (data, escape) {
                //return '<span class="tag is-info mb-1 mr-1">' + escape(data.text) + '</span>';
                if (this.items.length >= 3){
                    return '<span class="tag is-info mb-1 mr-1" style="display:none">' + escape(data.text) + '</span>';
                }else{
                    return '<span class="tag is-info mb-1 mr-1">' + escape(data.text) + '</span>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i got it. This is how you can achieve it:

```
<script>
    new TomSelect('#your_id', {
        plugins: ['checkbox_options'],
        onInitialize: function (){
            updateSelectedDisplay(this);
        },
        onItemAdd: function() {
            updateSelectedDisplay(this);
        },
        onItemRemove: function() {
            updateSelectedDisplay(this);
        }
    });
    function updateSelectedDisplay(instance) {
        selectedItems = instance.control.querySelectorAll('.item');
        var childElement = instance.control.querySelector('#ts-placeholder');
        var numSelected = selectedItems.length;

        if (numSelected > 1) {
            // hide all existing
            selectedItems.forEach(function(item){
                item.hidden = true
            })
            if (!childElement){
                // add dummy
                var divElement = document.createElement('div');
                // Set attributes
                divElement.setAttribute('id', 'ts-placeholder');
                // Set content
                divElement.textContent = numSelected + ' items selected';
                // Append the div element to the second last position of the desired parent element
                instance.control.insertBefore(divElement, instance.control.lastChild);
            } else {
                var childElement = instance.control.querySelector('#ts-placeholder');
                childElement.textContent = numSelected + ' items selected';
            }
        } else {
            selectedItems.forEach(function(item){
                item.hidden = false
            })
            var childElement = instance.control.querySelector('#ts-placeholder');
            if (childElement){
                instance.control.removeChild(childElement)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

To modify the threshold just modify `if (numSelected > 1)` according to your needs. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the behaviour of TomSelect that it resizes the input field. That might be tackled by adding custom css.